# Svelte store function update

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

Svelte store documentation shows String or Integer being updated, but I did not find any dynamic function in store.

I don't understand how to make the `getData` function as a writable in order to notify the html of the change.

In the following sample, I would like `b` to be shown after the `updateKey` function is called.

You will find a minimal code in REPL here: https://svelte.dev/repl/3c86bd48d5b5428daee514765c926e58?version=3.29.7

And the same code here in case REPL would be down:

App.svelte:

```
<script>
import { getData } from './store.js';
import { updateKey } from './store.js';
setTimeout(updateKey, 1000);
</script>

<h1>{getData()}!</h1>
```

store.js

```
import {setContext} from 'svelte';
import {writable} from 'svelte/store';

var data = {
    'a': 'a',
    'b': 'b'
};

var key = 'a';

export const getData = function() {
    return data[key];
}

export const updateKey = () => {
    key = 'b';
}
```

The goal is to work with a dynamic function in the store.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I think you still have a bit of confusion about how things work in Svelte... Not sure how to best answer your question, so here's some code for what's you're trying to achieve, along with some comments. I hope it will help you better understand how things come together in regards to stores.

`App.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'
    import { key, data, updateKey } from './store.js'

    onMount(() => {
        // it's not safe to have an unchecked timer running -- problems would
        // occur if the component is destroyed before the timeout has ellapsed,
        // that's why we're using the `onMount` lifecycle function and its
        // cleanup function here
        const timeout = setTimeout(updateKey, 1000);
        
        // this cleanup function is called when the component is destroyed
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timeout)
        }
    })

    // this will log the value of the `key` store each time it changes, using
    // a reactive expression (a Sveltism)
    $: console.log($key)
</script>

<!--
  NOTE: we're using the $ prefix notation to access _the value_ of the store,
        and not `data`, which would be _the store itself_ (an object with
        subscribe, set, etc.)
  -->
<h1>{$data}</h1>
```

`store.js`

```js
import { writable, derived } from 'svelte/store'

const db = {
    'a': 'a',
    'b': 'b'
}

// a writable store with initial value 'a'
export const key = writable('a')

export const updateKey = () => {
    // a writable store has a `set` method to change its value
    key.set('b')
}

// you can use a derived store to compute derived values from
// the current value of other stores
//
// here, we're getting the value from the db when the value of
// the `key` store changes
export const data = derived([key], ([$key]) => db[$key])
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This does exactly what I had in mind with great comments.

I will take a moment to understand the derived behavior.

Comment: I updated the REPL : https://svelte.dev/repl/3c86bd48d5b5428daee514765c926e58?version=3.29.7
The core question was to pass the parameter in the store function. Is that possible ?

Comment: No this is not directly possible -- function calls are never reactive. What you can do is call your function in a reactive expression when the lang value changes. But IMO this function call is really trying to force some procedural style where a more functional approach would be far more natural for Svelte, and probably less bug prone in the end. For this, your function call would become changing the value of a `key` writable store, and the result would come from a derived store. Updated REPL to illustrate both approaches: https://svelte.dev/repl/7633dfdc70bb4eee80d0a87e4bd1a631?version=3.29.7

Comment: Thank you again for the second sample.
I think I may try to use the store as a something it is not like you are saying.
Maybe i'm missing the point of the store / reactive behaviour, got to work on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if I understood your question correctly, you want to be able to change the function (logic) that is executed by `getData()` and you want on each function change the html to be updated

for this use case you'll need to create your own custom store

as follows in `store.js`

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
// an object to hold our functions
const functions = {
        "funcA": () => {
            // do something
            return "whatevedata for a"
        },
        "funcB": () => {
            // do something
            return "the data of b"
        }
    }

// this how to create a custom store, taken from svelte documentation
function createCustomStore(defaultValue) {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(defaultValue);
    return {
        subscribe,
        //custom function change func where suppliedValue the value you input to the store
        // set() is a default function for a store to change it's value
        changeFunc: (suppliedValue) => set(functions[suppliedValue]),
        reset: () => set(defaultValue)
    };
}

export const getData = createCustomStore(() => "default");


export const updateKey = () => {
        // this to update which function the store uses
        getData.changeFunc("funcB")
}
```

in App.svelte

```
<script>
    
    import { getData } from './store.js';
    import { updateKey } from './store.js';
    
    setTimeout(function() {
        updateKey()
    }, 1000);
    

</script>

<h1>{$getData()}</h1>
```

we added the `$` to `getData` because it's a store that holds reference to functions and the `()` is there to execute any function referenced by `getData` store. since it is a store on each value change (function change) of `getData`, the html will be updated

here is a [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/9fb792271c324da5bf1df6ccc617a902?version=3.29.7) of the implementation