# How to return a derived function that use fetched data from db based on value of another writable value in svelte/svelte kit?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

I am trying to get my language table's data from db in store.js and modify that data based on the language user selected. So the selected language is a writable variable and I need to get a derived function that returns the modified data. Here is my code in store.js

```
import { writable, derived } from 'svelte/store'; 

export async function getData(endpoint){
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`${baseAPI}${endpoint}`);
        return res.data;
    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }
}
function getTypography(lang){
    let typography;
    try {
        const texts = getData('/language');
        texts.then((data)=>{
            typography = data.payload;
            console.log(typography);
            return filterTypography(typography, lang)
        }).catch((e)=>{
            console.log('error', e);
        })        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    }
}

function filterTypography(typography, lang){
    let textarray=[];
    typography.forEach((element, index) => {
        textarray[index]={
            'keyword':element.keyword,
            'value':element[lang]
        }
    });
    return textarray
}

export const key = writable('en')
export const updateKey = (lang) => {
    key.set(lang)
}
export const data = derived(key, $key => getTypography($key));
```

Here is the code in my +page.svelte

```
<script>
    import { key, data, updateKey } from '$lib/store.js'
    
    function changeLang(lang){
        console.log("clicked with", lang);
        updateKey(lang)
    }
   
    $: console.log($key)
</script>

<h1>{$data}</h1>
<button  on:click={() => changeLang('dk')} >Change to DK</button>
<button  on:click={() => changeLang('en')}>Change to EN</button>
```

I am getting 'undefined' data. I am just trying to print out the data variable for testing. Please note that, the console log that I am printing after getting the data from the API endpoint is showing the data successfully. Also, another thing, if I just use a function in store instead of the getTypography function, that returns different static array based on the language chosen, it works perfectly fine. So to my understanding the issue might be getting the data properly from db. What can I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derived store makes no sense in this context because the data is updated asynchronously. The problem being that `getTypography` is not returning anything, but being used in `data` as if that were the case.

Just make `data` a `writable` and update that when the language changes. I.e. use something like:

```js
key.subscribe($key => updateData($key))
```

Where the `updateData` function is analogous to `getTypography` but sets the `data` store.

Something like:

```js
const data = writable([]);
async function updateData(lang) {
    try {
        const languageData = await getData('/language');
        const typography = languageData.payload;

        data.set(filterTypography(typography, lang));
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    }
}
```

(You may want to add additional logic to invalidate previous requests to prevent race conditions.)

---

If data for all languages is requested at once, you can update a base store asynchronously and use a `derived` store just for the filtering. It should be based on both the language (`key`) **and** the store that is updated with all the language data.

An example of the principle:

```js
import { writable, derived } from 'svelte/store';

const key = writable('en');
const allData = writable({});
const data = derived([allData, key], ([$allData, $key]) => {
    return $allData[$key]; // Filter data based on language
});
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c7b4c2e361604fc2b55a2891d19c258f?version=3.52.0)

---

You could also rewrite `getTypography` to actually return the promise it creates internally, but then you would have to use something like `{#await}` everywhere you use `data`.

```js
async function getTypography(lang) {
    try {
        const data = await getData('/language');
        const typography = data.payload;

        return filterTypography(typography, lang);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
        // If you do not return anything here, the awaited store will be `undefined`
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't be able to implement your solution properly. But as I understood, as I am returning data from a function on a writable data change, I need to use derived. Not sure if my understanding is wrong. Anyway, I optimized it a bit more and here is a new question after the optimization. Can you take a look at it and give your suggestion regarding this?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/74123561/12435693

Comment: Derived makes no sense here, because the data is asynchronously requested. As I wrote in my answer, you could not use it unless you `await` it every time which makes it pretty much unusable. Hence you should create a `writable` store and just update that when the language is changed. Also, make sure to read up on promises and `async`/`await`, you do not appear to have fully internalized its mechanics (since `getTypography` is broken).

Comment: (I updated my answer with a more concrete example for updating a store.)

Comment: But the data is not updating asynchronously. I am trying to get the data once. And after that whenever the language get changed, the filterTypography function will just modify the already stored variable and return.

Comment: That seems questionable, design-wise, you get all the data and don't need most of it, most of the time. Anyway, in that case you still need to update something asynchronously, just add another store e.g. `allData`, update that with everything, then create a `derived` store based on that **and** the language and use `filterTypography` there.

Comment: Added an example to my answer.

Comment: Your solution working in REPL and in svelte page. But when I am trying to use it in store.js it is giving error as I am trying to assign value to a const $allData. And I need to maintain the store and component structure. 

The modified version I refered you to working fine just the issue is getting the data initially in the variable. That is why asked you to take a look at it

Comment: You cannot use [`$` syntax](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values) in plain JS files, you have to replace that with `store.set(...)`.

Comment: Ok. Here is how I implemented your one:

store.js
const key = writable('en');
 const allData = writable({});
 export const data = derived([allData, key], ([$allData, $key]) => {
  return $allData[$key];
 });

    export const updateLanguage = (lang) => {
        key.set(lang)
    }
 
 // Fake initial fetch
 setTimeout(() => {
  allData.set({
   'en': 'Greetings from England',
   'de': 'Greetings from Germany',
        }
        )
 }, 2000);

getting 'data undefined' in page

Comment: At first you should get `undefined` because the `allData` contains nothing. How you deal with the initial phase is up to you, e.g. you can wrap everything in an `{#if $data}`, while it is being loaded.

Comment: Yeah got that. but now on click en changing to dk is not working from page. data is becoming undefined onclick to update the key and not getting anything

Comment: Can you modify your REPL example to make it in store and page format? That would be great

Comment: I adjusted it, but the only thing that is different is the `allData.set` instead of `$allData = `.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can now make that work. Actually I am very new in svelte that's why was bothering you so much. But sadly, I can't make this solution work for my purpose. The solution you provided, I already saw something like this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64862161/svelte-store-function-update 

The thing is I don't want to get a specific value from the fetched data. I want to store the fetched data in a variable. And then want to get a modified version of that variable from another function based on a parameter. That's why I reposted the question with diffrent approach

Comment: You simply have to adapt the code. The entire raw data is already supposed to be in one store and the derived store can manipulate it *however you want*. If you cannot do that, you should really work on your fundamental JS skills first.